# Returning JSON from WCF Web Service

Tags: wcf, json

I am trying to return JSON from a WCF Web service but all I get is bad request when I visit the URL.

Here is the interface:

```
 [ServiceContract]
    public interface IHighWCFService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = "KnownZombies")]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET")]
        List<ZombieInfo> GetZombies(); 

        [OperationContract]
        void DoWork();
    }
```

Here is the implementation of the above interface:

```
public class HighWCFService : IHighWCFService
    {
        public void DoWork()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public List<ZombieInfo> GetZombies()
        {
            var zombies = new List<ZombieInfo>()
                              {
                                  new ZombieInfo() {FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe"},
                                  new ZombieInfo() {FirstName = "Mohammad", LastName = "Azam"}
                              };
            return zombies; 
        }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class ZombieInfo
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
```

I visit the following URL which results in 400 bad request:

```
http://localhost:22059/HighWCFService.svc/KnownZombies
```

The Web.Config looks like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
   <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="HighOnCodingWebApps.HighWCFServiceBehavior">
     <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
     <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
   </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <services>
   <service behaviorConfiguration="HighOnCodingWebApps.HighWCFServiceBehavior"
    name="HighOnCodingWebApps.HighWCFService">
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:22059/HighWCFService.svc" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="HighOnCodingWebApps.IHighWCFService">
     <identity>
      <dns value="localhost" />
     </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:22059/HighWCFService.svc" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
   </service>
  </services>
 </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: You'll need to enable tracing at the server to find out why WCF is considering the incoming request to be bad. The traces will have some exception which should explain the issue.

Comment: BTW I just added a WCF Service file to my Web Application project. I hope that is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- I think a 400 bad request error is genearated by some other problem not related
  to JSON.
- I also think that you have to serialize that list in a list
  of JSON objects in order to receive them since you're not using SOAP
  anymore. You can use this class [DATACONTRACTJSONSERIALIZER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx)

Comment: I think WCF takes care of the serialization! http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/167159/How-to-create-a-JSON-WCF-RESTful-Service-in-60-sec